# Migrate RequireJS domReady to Webpack Loader

Tags: javascript, webpack, requirejs, domready

I'm migrating a RequireJS project to Webpack and can't find a Webpack analog to `domReady`.

In RequireJS, I require a null module with the domReady loader plugin, which marks itself as loaded once it receives the DOMContentLoaded event.

```js
require(['dep1', 'dep2', 'domReady!'], function(){
    // This code is only executed AFTER DOMContentLoaded
});
```

In Webpack, I've seen people map this to the node package `requirejs-domready`, but neither package seems to function as a Webpack loader:

```js
module.exports = {
    resolveLoader: {
        alias: {
            'domReady': 'requirejs-domready'
        }
    },
}
```

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/requirejs-domready/domReady.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/requirejs-domready/domReady.js):
ReferenceError: define is not defined
```

Is there anything similar available in Webpack or a way to configure this module as a Webpack loader?